# Cannot read a file using cordova file plugin in an Ionic 2 project

Tags: typescript, base64, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to use the [Cordova file plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) to read an image saved in a mobile device so I can then get the base64 encoding of it, which I need to store remotely. The problem is that the resolveLocalFilesystemUrl() method, which is supposed to provide a File Entry object, instead seems to be returning an Entry object, which means I can't call file on it.

Here is the code that should be getting the File Entry object so I can use the file method to read the file itself.

```
MediaCapture.captureImage().then((images)=>{
  self.image = images[0].localURL;
  File.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(self.image).then((entry)=>{
    entry.file(function (file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function (encodedFile) {
        var src = encodedFile.target.result;
        src = src.split("base64,");
        var contentAsBase64EncodedString = src[1];
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    })
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  })
})
```

I am getting the following Typescript error, which tells me resolveLocalFilesystemUrl() is resolving with an Entry object, which doesn't have a file method. (The plugin documentation says resolveLocalFilesystemUrl resolves with a File Entry object, and such an object definitely has a file method which provides the file itself):

```
Property 'file' does not exist on type 'Entry'.
```

I have experimented with the type of path I am providing resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(). I have tried full paths along the lines of /var/mobile/Applications//Documents/path/to/file and local URLs along the lines of cdvfile://localhost/temporary/filename - neither works

So the specific quesiton is why won't resolveLocalFilesystemUrl() provide me a File Entry object, or how I get it to do so? More generally, how can I read a file in Ionic 2 so that I can get a base64 version of it, if the above approach won't work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

I discovered that this problem was related to Typescript. resolveLocalFilesystemUrl() was actually resolving with a File Entry object (when I passed it a local url as the file path), but Typescript thought it was an Entry object and didn't think file() could be called on it.

The below fixed the issue by telling Typescript that `entry` object could be of any type, so could have any function or property called on it.

```
MediaCapture.captureImage().then((images)=>{
  self.image = images[0].localURL;
  File.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(self.image).then((entry: any)=>{
    entry.file(function (file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function (encodedFile: any) {
        var src = encodedFile.target.result;
        src = src.split("base64,");
        var contentAsBase64EncodedString = src[1];
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    })
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  })
})
```

Note that I also had to use `encodedFile: any` in order to allow target.result to be called on `encodedFile`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar Problem in Ionic3 with `@ionic-native/camera`, the error was being given by `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` and I solved it changing it to `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`. This is how my Project looks like:

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';
import { Image } from '****';

export class CameraService {
  public readonly cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {
    sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    correctOrientation: true
  };

  constructor(public camera: Camera) { }

  public takePicture(): Observable<Image> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.camera.getPicture(this.pictureOptions)).map(imageSrc => {
      this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageSrc;
      return new Image('CameraPhoto.jpeg', this.base64Image);
    });
  }
}
```

Class Image looks like

```
export class Image {
  public readonly name: string;
  public readonly fileURI: string;
  public readonly file?: File;

  constructor(name: string, fileURI: string, file?: File) {
    this.name = name;
    this.fileURI = fileURI;
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

I hope it could help someone.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

That is because `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` is  `window` object's function and not file.

```
MediaCapture.captureImage().then((images)=>{
  self.image = images[0].localURL;
  window.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(self.image).then((entry)=>{
    entry.file(function (file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function (encodedFile) {
        var src = encodedFile.target.result;
        src = src.split("base64,");
        var contentAsBase64EncodedString = src[1];
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    })
  }).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error);
  })
})
```

Or you could use ionic native version of the same plugin [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/file/)

Comment: I am using the Ionic Native version of the plugin, which is why I call resolveLocalFilesystemUrl on File. I've actually discovered that the problem was related to Typescript - when I specify that entry can be of any type, the problem goes and the function works fine. I'll add an answer for others' reference...