# Cannot get the file data after do resolveLocalFilesystemUrl in typescript [ionic angular]

Tags: angular, file, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the absolute path of a file by using the ionic native plugin *file chooser*, *file path*, and *file* which will be transferred to the rest api.

So, here is how my code looks like :

```
getFile(){
  this.fileChooser.open().then((uri)=>{
    // First, getting the file uri then do the resolve
    (<any>window).FilePath.resolveNativePath(uri, (path)=>{
      // (path) output is something like file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/eng3.pdf
      this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(path).then((entry: any)=>{
        entry.file((resFile)=>{
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = (encodedFile: any)=>{
            alert(encodedFile);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(resFile);
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I'm able to get the `path` of the file after do the `resolveNativePath()` and see the output by doing the `alert()`. So I tried to see the data that been processed with the `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl()` but it's returning no value.

I'm now lost track of the flow as I am unable to see the result and not sure what's happening on that function. I followed some tutorial from http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-serving-images-with-firebase-storage/ and do some editing on my code based on others practice from this discussion [Cannot read a file using cordova file plugin in an Ionic 2 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536303/cannot-read-a-file-using-cordova-file-plugin-in-an-ionic-2-project#41552675)

Comment: I have the same issue, have you find a solution to this?